# Снялась репутация

Tags: поддержка, репутация, голоса-против

Скажите пожалуйста почему у меня сейчас куча репутации снялась просто так??? 7 раз по -5 с пометкой "Массовое голосование отменено". Почему так???

Comment: [Справка, сэр.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

Comment: @D-side но я ни за что не голосовал!!!

Comment: Кто-то голосовал **за вас**.

Comment: за вас кто-то массово голосовал. его голоса откатили. это не ваша вина

Comment: Эмм но репутация то снялась мне...

Comment: но перед эти вам ее накинули

Comment: Странная система... Первый раз такое вижу))) Кстати раз уж мне удалось наконец то создать тут сообщение (дурацкий лимит символов) скажите еще пожалуйста на форуме есть приватные сообщения? Никак не нахожу...

Comment: приватных сообщений здесь нет, и кстати это не форум

Comment: А не могло так получится что я сам за себя проголосовал, а мне потом сняли? Просто репы реально больше было... В том смысле что когда сам за себя голосуешь ведь ошибку выдает и репутация не прибавляется.

Comment: нет, за самого себя проголосовать невозможно

Comment: Случаи - они всякие бывают... Мне сегодня, например, отмена массового голосования прибавила +6 баллов - кто-то, видно, очень старался зарубить репутацию :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Вчера за вас кто-то проголосовал 11 раз подряд:

[image]

Это было сделано в короткий промежуток времени однимпользователем. Система считает такие действия целевой накруткой (для плюсов) или целевым минусованием (для минусов) и откатывает их через некоторое время.

[image]

Замечу, откатились только 7 голосов.

Comment: ждем пока откатятся голоса за ответы? :)

Comment: Как то обидно получается, дали а потом отобрали)))

Comment: А можно узнать что за сволочи меня минусуют не за что?

Comment: @DarkByte, нет.

Comment: @DarkByte, не думаю. Да и у вас всего 3 минуса за время жизни на RU.SO

Comment: Обычно вопросы минусуют за низкое качество. Ответы еще и за некорректность.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, один участник проголосовал 7 раз в 11:51, остальные 4 голоса - от других участников.