# Постоянно снимается 2 балла репутации

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Частенько стал подмечать, что моя репутация становится ниже на 2. Вчера вечером 1207, сегодня уже 1205. Самый наглядный пример — когда я только перешагнул за 1000: репутация из 1007 постепенно снизилась до 999, и для меня оказался недоступным свежеприобретённый функционал для участников с ≥1000 баллами.

Естественно предположить, что ставят минусы. Но я их не вижу во всплывающей статистике последних достижений, соответственно, не могу понять, к каким сообщениям они относятся, чтобы подумать над этими вопросами и ответами более основательно.

[image: Статистика последних достижений]

Если дело действительно в минусах, полагаю, то, что в одних случаях они видны, а в других — нет, серьёзное упущение.

Другая версия — обнаружена накрутка голосов. Но тогда удалялось бы количество баллов, [кратное пяти](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2877/199934), а не двум.

Почему с меня может сниматься репутация?

Comment: Даже если действительно минусы иногда не видны, это далеко от серьёзного упущения. Серьёзное - это когда утекают данные пользователей или сервер рекламной статистики пятисотит.

Comment: Что с этим вопросом? Ответ вас удовлетворяет? Если нет, задавайте уточняющие вопросы, если да, то есть смысл принять ответ.

Answer (score 18):

Способы потерять 2 балла репутации:

- Минус на один из ваших вопросов или ответов (видно на странице репутации)
- Удален вопрос или ответ, где есть ваша правка, подтвержденная другими участниками. (не видно на странице репутации)