# Периодическое пропадание двух баллов репутации

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, репутация

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. В августе, как и везде обычно (и в интернете, и IRL) случается спад активности. У меня случилось так, что к моменту спада активности на ruSO я набрал 1999 баллов репутации (не смейтесь, я не специально). Потом я получил 2 балла за правку, в итоге баллов стало 2001, я перестал получать баллы за правки, но получил доступ к новым очередям проверок. Вопросы, на которые я мог бы ответить, появляться перестали. Через пару недель я увидел, что у меня сняли 2 балла, и их опять стало 1999. Через пару дней я опять сделал правку на 2 балла, опять получил 2001 балл. Потом еще какое-то время отвечать было не на что (и вообще отпуск), и примерно пару недель спустя опять минус два балла. Оба снижения никак не отражались в доступных логах (первый -  кубок в панели, второй - в профиле).
Что это было? Неужели просто совпадение? Обычно снятия репутации комментируются в логе (отмена плюса, галочки, удаление голосовавшего участника и т. д.), а тут тишина. Или это как-то связано с неактивностью? Я иногда по полгода вообще не захожу, но ничего не снималось раньше.
Точные даты не запомнил, к сожалению, первый раз - где-то в середине августа, ближе к концу наверное, второй - на прошлой неделе. В принципе, можно попробовать восстановить по истории проверок сообщений низкого качества: первая дата - между 24 и 27 августа, вторая - 14 или 15 сентября.

Comment: [**Похожий вопрос**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3035/199934). Спасибо.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Два других вопроса, в которых вы ранее делали правки были удалены.
Вместе с удалением откатились и два раза по +2 за правку:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717339
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/858637

Из списка правок эти правки тоже удалены.

Comment: а баллы полученные за ответы тоже аннулируются?